# visual studio not loading source file when debugging

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012

When debugging my application in visual studio my element is not loading the source file that is located on the local file system.

I feel this is a general question but i am using c# silverlight.

Im sure its in the project properties SOMEWHERE

Comment: You need matching PDB files and sources... VS usually says something along the lines "matching source for XXXX not found"... Also check if you are attaching debugger for matching type (native/managed/script/...)

Comment: Often doing a clean\rebuild cycle gets VS into a happier state.